# Why isnt gibbs free energy zero freely?

Tags: thermodynamics

On doing the following Gibbs free energy being zero merely:
$$Pressure \ constant$$
$$Temperature \ constant$$
$$dU=TdS-pdV$$
$$dU + d(pV) = TdS +VdP$$
$$dH=TdS+VdP$$
$$VdP=0 \ as \ dP=0$$
$$dH-TdS = dG = 0$$

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that Gibb's free energy has the relation:

$dG = Vdp - SdT$

If the pressure and the temperature are constant then $dp = dT = 0$ than
$dG = 0$.

If $dG = 0$ then it is not necessarily that $G=0$. $dG = 0$ is just the gradient of $G$, if $G$ is constant not equal to 0 for example then $dG = 0$.

Comment: Then for reactions at constant being temperature and pressure dG=0 then how are they being taking place?